# Not able to install and use Uniecart 2.2 on wamp

Tags: mysql

In backend i checked, the table are not creating and when installing stuck on same 2nd step page with an error in install.php.

error?: undefined exception

Comment: Please, describe the error you're having and the WAMP you're using in detail, so more people might understand it and help you.

Comment: on giving all the details on step 2 like localhost,mysql details. when i am clicking on next an error comes                                    Notice: Undefined index: table in \wamp\www\uni\UniEcart\install\install.php on line 54